# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip - installing pip behind proxy in python 2.7

Tags: python, pip

I am using **Phyton 2.7** where actually I want to **install pip**, so that I got **get-pip.py** from the website and trying to install pip using this command:

```
python get-pip.py
```

But it *getting failed after several retry and showing this problem*

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip
```

I searched different forums and found that maybe there is **proxy problem** as i am installing this behind a proxy so I found [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/), this command.

```
python get-pip.py --proxy="http://192.9.210.10:80"
```

But it is producing the same error. I have also tried this

```
python get-pip.py --proxy=192.9.210.10:80
```

Here, is the the error details:

[image]

Comment: Please include more of the log output before `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip`...

Comment: I have added the complete error details in question

Comment: The issue is the SSL (or lack of) failing.

Answer (score 0):

That might be a internet connection problem. Make sure you can access internet on the machine.

I was able to recreate same error turning off wifi:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, maybe i  have told that i am using this command behind a proxy.